# Nuget package error message on my project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8e72.jpg)

I have theses errors. It said that these package are not installed on my computer.

When I lanuch a restore from my solution, it said that the restoration is completed. But nothing change.

I have deleted these part from the .csproj :

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" />
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
</Target>
```

And reload my project. But nothing change.

What can I do to retrieve all my references ?

Comment: You just have to click on the blue link "error message" to see the picture. On the top of the post

Comment: try to run `update-package -reinstall` under `Tools`-->`NuGet Package Manager`-->`Package Manager Console`

Comment: Hi paralleles, any update about this issue? If you have any concern or the error still persists, please feel free to let us know and give you further support. If my answer helps you handle the issue, please do not forget to accept it:)

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

**First of all**, make a backup of your project.

**1)** First, remove any xml reference nodes like this(actually like the reference from the nuget packages) in `xxx.csproj` file:

```
 <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    .....
    .....
 </Reference>
    
    ..........
 <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" />


<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
</Target>
```

**2)** delete `bin` and `obj` folder

**3)** run `update-package -reinstall` under **Tools**-->**NuGet Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console**  to reinstall all your nuget packages based on your current PC's `nuget.config` file.

**Note**: this command is based on your current `packages.confg` file of your project. It reads the nuget packages which the `packages.config` file list and then reinstall them.

**Besides**, you can create a new project on VS IDE, and then just copy the `packages.config` file on the root of the new project, and then run `update-package -reinstall` to install them.

If it works well, then you can copy the rest of the old project's content into the new one.

This is equivalent to migrating to a new project.